# Equality on functions in $ \mathbb{R}^n $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $ f,g : M \subset \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^q $ continuous. Given $ a \in M $, supose that all open ball centered in $a$ contains a point $x$ such as $f(x) = g(x) $. Show that $ f(a) = g(a) $. Use this to show that if $f,g$ are  continuous real functions and $ f(x) = g(x) $ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$  then $ f \equiv g $.

Demonstration:

Since $f,g$ are continuous  $ x \in B(a,\delta) \implies f(x) \in B (f(a),\epsilon) $ and $ x \in B(a,\delta) \implies g(x) \in B (g(a),\epsilon) $ (in this case I'm already considering minimum delta that satisfies this). By the global continuity we have $ A = M \cap f^{-1}(B(f(a), \epsilon) $ and $ B = M \cap g^{-1} (B ( g(a), \epsilon ) $.

Supose that for all $ x \in B(a,\delta) $ we find a $f(x)  \in B(f(a),\epsilon)$ and $ g(x) \in B(g(a),\epsilon ) $ such as $f(x) =  g(x)$. Since they are open balls and continuous we have a neigborhood in $f(a)$ (and also in $g(a)$ ) such as all points on image are equal in particular $ f(a) = g(a) $.

My question is:
That proves the first proposition? 
Why there is need to restrict the second statement to rationals only? Isn't it valid to all reals? (can we find a counter example?) How can we prove this? (i could not find any way besides saying that is valid for all real function therefore is valid to rationals.

Comment: You meant $f(x) = g(a)$ as hypothesis in the second line?

Comment: I meant $ \forall x g(x) = f(x) $

Comment: My proof can be adapted. Give me two minutes.

Comment: Thank you. ;-). My intuition in this proof is something like, if you have a two functions and to every point in the domain the neighborhood of each one of these functions have the same image, then they are the same function.

Comment: The intuition is quite right. My tip for the future is to use and abuse of the words "any" and "exists", this can make the whole difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that you meant $f(x) = g(a)$ as a hypothesis in the second line, instead of $f(x) = f(a)$, otherwise I don't think it will work.

**Comments**:

> Since $f,g$ are continuous $x∈B(a,δ)⟹f(x)∈B(f(a),ϵ)$ and $x∈B(a,δ)⟹g(x)∈B(g(a),ϵ)$ (in this case I'm already considering minimum delta that satisfies this).

This is correct. However, I do recomend having the patience to write "Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then exists $\delta > 0$ such that...", that is, quantifying everything. This way you don't risk losing yourself in so many letters and variables.

> By the global continuity we have $A=M∩f^{−1}(B(f(a),ϵ)$ and $B=M∩g^{−1}(B(g(a),ϵ)$.

What are $A$ and $B$? Are you defining them now? Are you going to use them later?

> Supose that for all $x∈B(a,δ)$ we find a $f(x)∈B(f(a),ϵ)$ and $g(x)∈B(g(a),ϵ)$ such as $f(x)=g(x)$.

The only thing you could say is that we have $x \in B(a,\delta)$ such that $f(x) = g(a)$. We won't need to use $g(x)$ anywhere in this proof.

> Since they are open balls and continuous we have a neigborhood in $f(a)$ (and also in $g(a)$ ) such as all points on image are equal in particular $f(a)=g(a)$.

I don't see how this follows from your previous work. I mean, these balls could be disjoint, for all I know.

**An easier proof:**

If I want to prove that $f(a)=g(a)$, I want to prove that ${\rm d}(f(a),g(a)) = 0$, right? Try to translate everything in terms of $\Bbb R$, usually it will make your life easier. And if ${\rm d}(f(a),g(a)) < \epsilon$ *for all $\epsilon > 0$*, then ${\rm d}(f(a),g(a)) = 0$, it is a basic result from analysis.

Then let $\epsilon > 0$. By continuity, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that ${\rm d}(f(x),f(a)) < \epsilon$ for all $x \in B(a,\delta)$. Now, by our hypothesis, there exists a special element there, $x_0$, such that $f(x_0) = g(a)$. Then: $${\rm d}(f(a),g(a)) \leq \color{red}{{\rm d}(f(a),f(x_0))}+{\rm d}(\color{blue}{f(x_0)},g(a)) < \color{red}{\epsilon}+{\rm d}(\color{blue}{g(a)},g(a)) = \epsilon.$$
This way we conclude that ${\rm d}(f(a),g(a) )=0$.

**After the edit:** Let $\epsilon > 0$. Take $\delta > 0$ small enough so that ${\rm d}(f(x),g(x)) < \epsilon/2$ and ${\rm d}(g(x),g(a)) < \epsilon/2$, for all $x \in B(a,\delta)$. Now, take the special $x_0 \in B(a, \delta)$ which satisfies $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$. So: $${\rm d}(f(a),g(a)) \leq {\rm d}(f(a),f(x_0))+\require{cancel} \cancelto{0}{{\rm d}(f(x_0),g(x_0))}+{\rm d}(g(x_0),g(a))<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$

The second part is a strightforward application of this result. If you manage to understand my proof, you will manage to write this second part neatly (nevertheless, I can give one more hand if you need it).

---

**Let's learn more!**

In the same way we did in your other question later, let's state and prove a result for metric spaces (you did noticed that my work above goes for arbitrary metric spaces, right?). Let $M,N$ be metric spaces.

> **Lemma:** Let $f,g:M \to N$ be continous functions. Then $F = \{x\in M \mid f(x) = g(x)  \}$ is closed in $M$.

**Proof:** I'll give two proofs:

- Define $\phi: M \to \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ by $\phi(x) = {\rm d}(f(x),g(x))$. Then $\phi$ is continuous because ${\rm d},f$ and $g$ are. Notice that $F = \phi^{-1}(\{0\})$ is the inverse image of a closed set by a continuous function, hence closed.
- Take a sequence $(p_n)_{n \in \Bbb Z_{>0}}$ such that $p_n \to p\in M$. So $f(p_n) = g(p_n)$. Since this goes for all $n$, take the limit: $\lim f(p_n) = \lim g(p_n)$. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, the limit goes in $f(\lim p_n) = g(\lim p_n) \implies f(p) = g(p)$, and so $p \in F$. So $F$ is closed.

> **Proposition:** Let $f,g: M \to N$ be continuous funtions. If $D \subset M$ is a dense subset (that is, $\overline{D} = M$) and $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in D$, then $f \equiv g$.

**Proof::** Recall that $\overline{D}$ is the "smallest" *closed* subset containing $D$ (meaning that any closed set which contains $D$, contains $\overline{D}$ too). In the notation of the last proof, let $F$ be the set of points in which $f$ and $g$ coincide. Clearly $F \subset M$. And since $F$ is closed, by the remark above we have: $$D \subset F \implies M = \overline{D} \subset F,$$ so these inclusions give us that $F= M$, that is, the functions are equal on all of $M$.

So the second part of your exercise follows from the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, that is, $\overline{\Bbb Q}= \Bbb R$.

Comment: @Lin By the way, I like the way you always include your attempts at solving the problem. I wish more people did this. I think this is the largest answer I've ever written in MSE `:P`

Comment: Thank you very much for the compliment. I'm still learning. I know that if I just post questions here is something like "please someone do my homework", and that is not what I want. Also as you stated above, I'm pretty verbose when I dont need (that is happens because I really don't know where to go after) and some times I do not write what I have to (because I'm lazy with the mathematical bureaucracy).

Comment: I think it is a matter of practice, you'll eventually get there. I'm sure of it. Check my edit `:)`